# HTTP Status 404 - /ks-with-rice-bundled/kew/ActionList.do

Tags: apache, tomcat6, kuali

**On Front End below screen comes up when we enter into kuali Student login UI with admin/admin account.**

> HTTP Status 404 - /ks-with-rice-bundled/kew/ActionList.do
>
> type Status report
>
> message /ks-with-rice-bundled/kew/ActionList.do
>
> description The requested resource is not available.

**This is the error I get in the log file:**

```
192.168.0.134 - - [21/Jan/2016:15:33:00 +0530] "POST /ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm/org.kuali.student.lum.lu.ui.main.LUMMain/rpcservices/ServerPropertiesRpcService HTTP/1.1" 200 46
192.168.0.134 - - [21/Jan/2016:15:33:00 +0530] "POST /ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm/org.kuali.student.lum.lu.ui.main.LUMMain/rpcservices/SecurityRpcService HTTP/1.1" 200 21
192.168.0.134 - - [21/Jan/2016:15:33:00 +0530] "POST /ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm/org.kuali.student.lum.lu.ui.main.LUMMain/rpcservices/MetadataRpcService HTTP/1.1" 200 4745
192.168.0.134 - - [21/Jan/2016:15:33:00 +0530] "POST /ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm/org.kuali.student.lum.lu.ui.main.LUMMain/rpcservices/ServerPropertiesRpcService HTTP/1.1" 200 355
192.168.0.134 - - [21/Jan/2016:15:33:00 +0530] "POST /ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm/org.kuali.student.lum.lu.ui.main.LUMMain/rpcservices/ServerPropertiesRpcService HTTP/1.1" 200 179
192.168.0.134 - - [21/Jan/2016:15:33:00 +0530] "POST /ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm/org.kuali.student.lum.lu.ui.main.LUMMain/rpcservices/SecurityRpcService HTTP/1.1" 200 204
192.168.0.134 - - [21/Jan/2016:15:33:00 +0530] "GET /ks-with-rice-bundled/kew/ActionList.do HTTP/1.1" 404 1027
192.168.0.134 - - [21/Jan/2016:15:33:01 +0530] "POST /ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm/org.kuali.student.lum.lu.ui.main.LUMMain/rpcservices/SecurityRpcService HTTP/1.1" 200 287
```

**Cataline.out logs gives below one:**

```
2016-01-21 15:33:00,760 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] u:/d: INFO  org.kuali.student.common.ui.server.gwt.ServerPropertiesRpcGwtServlet - Property not found, looking in Context: ks.rice.actionList.serviceAddress with value: http://kuali.localdomain:8080/ks-with-rice-bundled/kew/ActionList.do
2016-01-21 15:33:00,804 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] u:/d: INFO  org.kuali.student.common.ws.ServletWrappingController - handleRequestInternal : SecurityGwtServlet
2016-01-21 15:33:00,818 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] u:/d: INFO  org.kuali.student.common.ws.ServletWrappingController - handleRequestInternal : SecurityGwtServlet
```

I can see in the error, what is it, however I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Is there anyone can help me out with this?

Comment: 404 erro means "not found". Check if ks-with-rice-bundled/kew/ActionList.do file exists or if have the proper access permissions

Comment: Thanks Joao for pointing it out, however the problem was something else which i got below from Ken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your successful POSTs are to /ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm/... but the 404 is on /ks-with-rice-bundled. Rice configuration is leading to a redirect to the incorrect location.

I would either deploy the application to /ks-with-rice-bundled or add

```
<param name="app.code">ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm</param>
```

to your local ks-config.xml.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Above code did not help much in my case, however what i did is to change the - <param name="app.context.name">ks-with-rice-bundled-2.0.3-cm</param>. However your guidance helped me.